# Redshift copy from STDIN using java program

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have Java program that works fine on Postgres, but while in migration to Redshift, I want this Postgres program to run on Redshift.

In Postgres I used following classes, and I'm trying to use same in Redshift.

```
import org.postgresql.copy.CopyIn;
import org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager;
import org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection;

following is the program snapshot :
Connection insertConnection = OpenDBConnection(prop);

CopyIn cpIN = null;  
CopyManager cm = new CopyManager((BaseConnection) insertConnection);
cpIN = cm.copyIn("COPY table_name (col1,col2) FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER '|'");

but I'm getting following error:
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException:com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.S41NotifiedConnection cannot be cast to    org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection

Basically, what the program does is, it copy some records from db table, it put is STDIN, proram processes the records, filters and copy to other db table.

Comment: this site is not to offload work, but help you with specific problems you can not solve yourself. you have to show some effort of your own. what did you try? how did it fail?

Comment: I don't think you can use the CopyManager API with Redshift's modified PgJDBC. If you can, it'll use a different API or at least different class name. You will need one class for Redshift and one for normal PostgreSQL, then decide which to use based on the connection type.

Comment: @Craig Ringer : thanks Craig. CopyManager API is not supported in Redshift. can u suggest what equivalent I can use for Redshift. using seperate class would not work in my scenario.

Answer (score 8):

It is **not possible** to use `COPY...FROM STDIN`.

The [Amazon Redshift COPY documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) shows:

```
COPY table_name 
[ column_list ]
FROM data_source
[ WITH ] CREDENTIALS [AS] 'aws_access_credentials'
[ [ FORMAT ] [ AS ] data_format ] 
[ [ parameter [ argument ] [, ... ] ]
```

where `data_source` is one of:

- COPY from Amazon S3
- COPY from Amazon EMR
- COPY from Remote Host (SSH)
- COPY from Amazon DynamoDB

The most efficient way to copy data into Redshift is to place it in Amazon S3 and then use the `COPY` command. This performs a parallel load across all nodes and supports GZIP format (reducing file storage and making loading faster).